# Python: Having trouble using .bind() on anything not involving the mouse

Tags: python, canvas, bind

I can make a basic python application like so:

```
from tkinter import *

block = None

def moveUp(event):
    field.move(block,0,-50)

root = Tk()

field = Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 'light blue')
field.pack()


block = field.create_rectangle(100,100,110,110)

field.bind('<Button-1>',moveUp)

mainloop()
```

and it will behave just like you would expect. It creates a square on a Canvas and moves that square up 50 pixels every time you click in the Canvas.

However, When I replace

```
field.bind('<Button-1>',moveUp)
```

to, for example,

```
field.bind('<Return>',moveUp)
```

the square does not move, no matter how many times I press the Enter key.  This problem persists for any kind of keyboard input (e.g `<space>`, etc), but any input involving the mouse is fine.

Any input at all is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `field` does not have focus, and therefore does not capture the keypress. One option is simply to make the binding more general:

```
field.bind('<Return>',moveUp)
```

to

```
root.bind('<Return>',moveUp)
```

Another option is to set the focus to the `field`:

```
field.bind('<Return>',moveUp)
field.focus_set()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what's the reason, but it seems to work if you use `bind_all` instead of `bind`.

```
field.bind_all('<Return>',moveUp)
```

My guess is that using the keyboard, the canvas does not have focus and so does no register the event. Using `bind_all`, the event is registered when any widget of the application has focus.

See here for some information on [levels of binding](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/binding-levels.html).